S3 bucket image is giving CORS error loading Image
I am basically using canvas to let users highlight regions on image that will be used to feed the AI model to do it's working.
The problem is that when I load the Image from the S3 bucket it gives a CORS error
This is how I am loading the image.
(Ignore the code within the onload function. That is to keep track of a mask)
useEffect(() => {
  if (imageData) {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const maskCanvas = maskCanvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const maskcontext = maskCanvas.getContext("2d");
    const image = new Image();
    image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    image.onload = () => {
      canvas.width = 400;
      const aspectRatio = image.naturalWidth / image.naturalHeight;
      canvas.height = canvas.width / aspectRatio;
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      drawBackgroundImage(context, image, canvas);

      if (maskCanvas.width != 400) {
        maskCanvas.width = 400;
        maskCanvas.height = maskCanvas.width / aspectRatio;
        if (maskImageData) {
          const maskImage = new Image();
          maskImage.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
          maskImage.onload = () => {
            maskcontext.drawImage(
              maskImage,
              0,
              0,
              maskCanvas.width,
              maskCanvas.height
            );
          };
          maskImage.src = maskImageData;
        } else {
          maskcontext.fillStyle = "black";
          maskcontext.fillRect(0, 0, maskCanvas.width, maskCanvas.height);
        }
      }
    };
    image.onerror = (e) => {
      toast.error("Failed to load image");
    };
    image.src = imageData;
  }
}, [imageData]);


I added the CORS policy to the S3 bucket but it is not working
[
  {
    "AllowedHeaders": [
      "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
      "GET",
      "POST",
      "PUT",
      "DELETE",
      "HEAD"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
      "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
      "ETag",
      "x-amz-meta-custom-header"
    ],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
  }
]


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
